# Creating JSON Object Pojo for json String

Tags: java, json

I have a scenario like this in which  need to be converted to object using Object mapper .Hence i create a proerty like below to capture OrderDispatchItemDTO.

```
@JsonProperty("OrderDispatchItemDTO")
    private OrderDispatchItemDTO orderDispatchItemsDTO;

{
  "Message": {

    "MessageData": {
      "OrderDispatchDTO": {
        "StartDateTime": "2017-05-19T02:45:00",
        "Details": {
          "OrderDispatchItemDTO": {
          more json properties
          }
        },
        "EndDateTime": "2017-05-19T05:45:00",
      }
    },
    "StatusID": 1,
  }
}
```

But if OrderDispatchItemDTO comes as list then my mapper fails as its not able to parse the json string

```
 @JsonProperty("OrderDispatchItemDTO")
        private List<OrderDispatchItemDTO> orderDispatchItemsDTO;




  {
          "Message": {

            "MessageData": {
              "OrderDispatchDTO": {
                "StartDateTime": "2017-05-19T02:45:00",
                "Details": [
                  "OrderDispatchItemDTO": {
                  more json properties
                  },
"OrderDispatchItemDTO": {
                  more json properties
                  }
                ],
                "EndDateTime": "2017-05-19T05:45:00",
              }
            },
            "StatusID": 1,
          }
        }
```

fix is          mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

Comment: Any exception ?

Comment: Have you tried **JSON.parse()** [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

Comment: Yup the porblem is i am crated one Object which  which directly maps the json string to object .but in some scenarios  OrderDispatchItemDTO can be a single  object or can be multiple objects.So in the Java POJO  either i can make it like LIST<OrderDispatchItemDTO > or OrderDispatchItemDTO . now suppose i kept it as LIST  and  in json string tags are there of OrderDispatchItemDTO  then it will work fine.but if single tag is there .it will fail

Comment: error:Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token

Comment: your second JSON is invalid. Because the `Details` field contains 2 property with the same name `OrderDispatchItemDTO`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @JsonAnySetter attribute and set your list dynamically. Here is an example. In my case one property can be either a number or an object, so here is how I solved it simply:

```
@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    try {
        if (name.equals("property") && value != null) {
            MyObject t = null;
            if (value instanceof Long) {
                t = new MyObject();
                t.setId((Long) value);
            } else if (value instanceof LinkedHashMap) {
                t = mapper.convertValue(value, MyObject.class);
            }
            //putting t anywhere i.e. setting property
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks  for sharing...my issue got resolved with updating mapper property.